# Is there a way to see who the permission set is assigned to in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visualstudiocode

Is it possible to see who the permission set is assigned to on the one screen? I know I can do this within Salesforce but its a lot of clicking and slower so if there is a faster way where I can see it all at once that would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Assuming you have Salesforce extension pack installed, you can run a SOQL query within vscode: `SELECT Assignee.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSet.Name = 'a_name'`

Comment: Thank you Hengky!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have Salesforce extension pack installed in vscode, you can run a SOQL query within vscode:

```sql
SELECT Assignee.Name
FROM PermissionSetAssignment
WHERE PermissionSet.Name = 'a_name'
```

If you want to find out the profile or role of the assigned users:

```sql
SELECT Assignee.Name, Assignee.Profile.Name, Assignee.UserRole.Name
FROM PermissionSetAssignment
WHERE PermissionSet.Name = 'a_name'
```

The `Profile` field in the PermissionSet object is a reference to the Profile object if a permission set is owned by a profile.
See [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm).

The profile and permission objects model is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_profile_permissions.htm).

Comment: Hey Hengky, this is exactly what I am looking for. Appreciate the help. Still very new to this and find it difficult to understand how all this works but I'm getting there

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found some SOQL queries that I can use.

SELECT Id, PermissionSetId, PermissionSet.Name, PermissionSet.ProfileId, PermissionSet.Profile.Name, AssigneeId, Assignee.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSet.Name = 'ABN_Lookup'

Now I noticed that the Profile Name shows up as empty for me. Why is that?

Any help would be great! Thank you

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to find out the profile of the assigned users? If so, then you can use `Assignee.Profile.Name`

Comment: Ah that worked! Whats the differencer between PermissionSet.Profile.Name and Assignee.Profile.Name?

Also where can one find out about the relationships between these objects that I can't physically see within Salesforce?

How do I mark ur comment as the correct one?

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to also the Role?

Comment: it's possible as there is a reference to Role object via PermissionSet.Assignee.UserRole. I have reposted my comments as an answer instead. Feel free to mark it if you would like to.